# A/C cold air kicks in 30 minutes or more after the blower comes on. Any ideas?

Tags: air-conditioning

The last two days the A/C unit has been operating differently. The blower comes on after getting the signal from the thermostat but no cold air. After 30 to 45 minutes cold air comes out and cools the house.

A/C unit was operating fine last week. Filters replaced a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Is the compressor unit outdoors running when the A/C is blowing warm air?

Comment: Turn off system for an hour or so. Then try turning on cool. If cool air blows very soon after  I would suspect the outside  compressor is not adequately cooling itself because of clogged fins or bad fan motor. This will cause compressor to shutdown until the motor cools down.    Also agree with TPE Comment you have to look at outside unit to see if it is running. Listen for a humming sound if it is not spinning. That may indicate a bad capacitor.

Comment: Thank you. Motor replaced last summer. When the A/C kicks in (30  minutes later)  warm is exhausted by the fan and the cooling tubing gets cold and it starts cooling the house. It is however taking longer to reach the preset thermostat setting. I will listen for  a humming noise.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is on start up it is most likely under charged ( usually due to a leak) when the system first starts up the system is cold, the gas is compressed this creates heat that is removed in the condenser coil,
 if there is not much gas it takes some time in this case once the compressor starts it is probably running close to 100% of the time As it is not cooling enough to shutdown. 
A recharge can fix this with most systems 
It may also Be a sticking thermal expansion valve can be the problem but I have not seen this very often and when that is the cause the unit will cycle funny.

Note if your system is R22 the cost is high $100/ lb and more so they may try and talk you into a new system.

Comment: Check the condenser, it may be iced up. If so the air flow will be noticeably reduced.